Laplace transform of probability density functions
I have a curious observation motivated by some applications of queueing theory. Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R^+$ be a PDF so that $\int_0^{+\infty}f(t)dt=1$. Let's say that $f$ is bounded and continuous. Consider the Laplace transform
$$
F(\omega)=\int_0^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-\omega t}dt
$$
for $\omega\in\mathbb C$. It is easy to see that $F(0)=1$ and $F(\omega)\neq 1$ on $Re(\omega)>0$. Also, for the exponential distribution $f(t)=\beta e^{-\beta t}$, it is easy to see that $\omega=0$ is the only root to $F(\omega)=1$.
My question is, under some decay conditions such as $|F(\omega)|=O(1/|\omega|)$ as $|\omega|\to\infty$, is it true that $F(\omega)=1$ has no root on $Re(\omega)<0$ if and only if $f$ is an exponential distribution? For example, if $f(t)=te^{-t}$ then there is a root $F(-2)=1$ too.

In your counter example $F(-2)$ is a diverging integral. Actually if $\mu$ is a probability on $R^+$ there exists a maximal $A\in[0,\infty]$ such that the Laplace transform is real analytic on $W=(-A,+\infty)$. In this case it is analytic  on the strip $W\times iR.$ The logarithm $k(w)$ of the Laplace transform is strictly convex on $W$ if $\mu$ is not Dirac and $k'(0)<0$. As a consequence $k(w)=0$ for $-A<w<0$ is impossible. However the fact that $k$ is meromorphic on the strip suggests that it can have zeros, but I have not constructed an example.
Finally, you are rather considering with your example $\frac{1}{(1+w)^2}$ an analytic continuation beyond $-A+iR$.This is not always possible and you need further hypothesis to confort your interesting conjecture.

Thank you Letac! My bad that I didn't notice the divergence issue on Re(w) < 0. Just curious: in this setting, how is the inverse Laplace transform usually evaluated? I previously thought I can do a change of variable to get $f(t)=\frac{e^{\gamma t}}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(\gamma + iu)e^{iut} du$ and then use Jordan's lemma but now it seems that semi circle included region is diverging.
